# In a custom Racket language, how can I define a recursive macro?

Tags: macros, racket

I am trying to create a recursive macro in a custom Racket language. 
However, while the macro expands properly with `#lang racket`, it fails when implemented with my new language.

For example, here is the recursive definition of a simple macro `f` which expands to its last argument:

```lisp
;; my-lang.rkt
#lang racket

(provide #%datum
         #%module-begin
         define-syntax
         (for-syntax syntax-case
                     syntax
                     raise-syntax-error
                     #%app
                     quote
                     #%datum))
```

```lisp
#lang s-exp "my-lang.rkt"

(define-syntax (f stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ x) #'x]
    [(_ x xs ...) #'(f xs ...)]
    [_ (raise-syntax-error 'f "bad syntax" stx)]))


(f 1 2 3) ; =>  f: bad syntax in: (f 2 3)
```

Why isn't `(f 2 3)` matched and expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `...` to the provided identifiers.

```
#lang racket
(provide #%datum
         #%module-begin
         define-syntax

         (for-syntax syntax-case
                     syntax
                     raise-syntax-error
                     #%app
                     quote
                     quote-syntax
                     ...
                     #%datum))
```